# Is their any difference between red and white ball?

Tags: cricket

I have realized that it is very hard to play with red ball for the batsman like in test matches when he plays any unnecessary shot like from outside the off stump he gets out immediately.
The scenario is completely different with white ball.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between balls in Test and ODI Cricket?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/what-is-the-difference-between-balls-in-test-and-odi-cricket)

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the balls, or the difference between (e.g.) the wide rules in tests and ODIs?

Comment: No.. I am talking about the nature of balls.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate then